# How to i get pdf file in view format without save or save as option while downloading

Tags: java, image, pdf

How to i get pdf file in view format without save or save as option while downloading. any one can help me for this scenario and give sample code. here is my code for download and save format.

```
File f= new File(file);
if(f.exists()){
    ServletOutputStream op= response.getOutputStream();
    response.reset();
    if(check==1){
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    }else{
        response.setContentType(content);
    }
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=" +fileName);
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(buf)) != -1)){
        op.write(buf,0,length);
    }
    in.close();
    op.flush();
    op.close();
}
```

Comment: just for clarification, you do not want to download the file?

Comment: Do you need any more help?

Answer (score 1):

To indicate to the browser that the file should be viewed in the browser:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to

```
response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=" +fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do anything to open pdf directly on browser, 
just use `response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline;)` instead of attachment .